# access struct fields in a concurrent way using threads

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, mutex

suppose I have a data structure with a lot of fields. I want to access it in a concurrent way using threads. Anyway I don't want to lock the entire struct (eg with a completely exclusive access to it using a big mutex ) but i'd like that a thread can access a field even if other threads are accessing OTHER fields.
Is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: This smacks of premature optimization to me.  You are going to have a lot more complexity with locks around each field.  I would only do this if a profiler tells you that it is a performance issue.

Comment: Any particular language? You will get more views if you put a language tag.

Comment: Do you need to access it in order to *mutate* the field? Or just read from it? If you're mutating the fields, then you'll need a complicated locking scheme in order to get efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Java has [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) and ConcurrenSkipListSet that work really, really well for situations like this.  It also has a ConcurrentHashMap that's not quite so fast in a multithreaded environment but is thread-safe.  I'd think something similar would be available in most languages.  The skip list idea (a singly-linked list that acts like a dictionary/map and uses compare-and-swap rather than locking) is rather new, but hash tables that do their own locking have been around forever.  (If you don't use Java and can't find something, Java is open source, so you *could* translate the code and make your own.)

Answer (score 0):

Well the straightforward way would be to have a separate mutex protecting each field, assuming you can afford the memory overhead.

**Edit**: Since you're talking about a hash table, locking each slot would produce too much overhead, while a single lock would be too inefficient.

The most acceptable way would be a lock-striping technique, which means maintaining K locks, each protecting `M/K` slots (with M the total number of slots). You can then run some benchmarks and tune K for optimal performance.

Comment: It is for a hash table... how many fields should be there? (is there any non-straightforward method?)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having big pile of locks you can have only one for the whole hash table, BUT employing a flag for each element in the table. Flag denotes that the element is currently used by someone else, and that whoever wants to use it must wait a little. So, to obtain an element from the table  you go through single lock, but as soon as element is obtain you release it. After that you check if you are allowed to use the element. If not wait a little and check again.

If elements can be deleted from hash table you must have a reference count for each element, so that you may delete element and remove it from the table only when reference count drops to zero.

When new element is added to the table it is done so inside the table's lock. Lock is used for deleting elements too. Hopefully accessing existing elements is done more often than creating new ones and deleting the existing ones.